# How to avoid duplicating data when sending non-varying attributes to a WebGL shader?

Tags: javascript, shader, webgl

WebGL 1 doesn't seem to have support  for the [flat modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581271/flat-qualifier-in-glsl).

As a result, how do I avoid duplicating a ton of data when sending data to the vertex shader?

For example, in my use-case I have many lights to render (which are just a bunch of triangles clipped by a circular radius). So let's say each light point has a radius, tint, and center. If I were to do separate draw calls, this is trivial, as I can pass things like tint and radius as uniforms.

However, let's say I wanted to render all of my lights in one draw call. My intuition is that I would have to load the vertex buffer like so:

```
Triangle Points Attribute: X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, ...
Radius Attribute: 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100, ...
Center Attribute: X1, Y1, X1, Y1, X1, Y1, ...
Tint Attribute: 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, ...
```

This is because varyings are naturally interpolated, so unless I duplicate them, the attribute values will be interpolated from triangle to triangle, when in reality I desire they just stay static and unchanging, like a uniform. But they can't be a uniform because different light points have different radiuses, centers, tints, etc. As you can see, in the above, the only non-duplicated data are the triangle points. Everything else is just repeated over and over.

I suppose an alternative is to just have a separate draw call for each light point, but I'm not sure which is "better" practice. If I have separate draw calls, then I avoid duplicating data, but then I have to iterate through static every light in the game and redraw them all separately.

Ideally there would be a way to just pass attributes as non-varying so that I could avoid having to duplicate all this data, but I'm not sure how to do that. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I inderstand you correctly you're building a vertex buffer with a triangulated circle for each of your lights in it? If so this is not a matter of flat vs interpolated varyings (data passed from one shader stage to the other) fed by attributes but just a matter of "how do I not set my light properties on each vertex of the light primitive" in which case you can either use instanced drawing (available through [extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ANGLE_instanced_arrays/drawArraysInstancedANGLE) in WebGL1) or you fetch the data via a texture lookup in the vertex shader. If you're not memory bound duplication is probably the fastest of the bunch though.

Drawing each light individually would be quite inefficient.